# Empty file output from calling external program with output redirection in C++

Tags: c++, command-line, command, io-redirection, external-process

From C++ source, I execute the following line:

```
system("../BWAPI/ITUBot/Clingo/clingo.exe bwapi-data/AI/ITUBotWall.txt > bwapi-data/AI/solver-out.txt");
```

This line causes an empty `solver-out.txt` to be created. If I execute the same command using command line from outside the C++ program, the output file is successfully created with relevant contents.

The `ITUBotWall.txt` is created just before this command. Would this be relevant to the issue?

What would the reason be behind this? What am I missing and how can I solve this?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/A5ci7k).

Comment: I fixed it by using `iss(token)` instead of `iss << token`. Then deleted the question.

Comment: Both should work, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make all paths absolute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -:
`system("../BWAPI/ITUBot/Clingo/clingo.exe < bwapi-data/AI/ITUBotWall.txt > bwapi-data/AI/solver-out.txt");`

Comment: No difference. Still empty file.

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the paths of the files correctly ? Try entering full absolute paths. Instead of `bwapi-data/AI/ITUBotWall.txt` , try `<partition letter>:/.../bwapi-data/AI/ITUBotWall.txt`. Same for output file and executable file.

Comment: I'm sure because the solver-out.txt is generated by this line.

Comment: Write `perror("")` just after the `system()` line in your code. Do you get any error message?

Comment: I am not using `stdout`, I am debugging using in-game text. So I printed  `_doserrno` before and after the system call. The output is Before :3, After :0. Seems like there's no error after calling the external program.